# JavaScript In Kendo Upload Save Object

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

At the moment, my Kendo upload looks like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
    .Name("UploadPicker")
    .TemplateId("fileTemplate")
    .Async(a => a
        .Save("UploadDepotLogo", "Depot",new {depotID = Model.DepotID})
        .Remove("Remove", "Upload")
        .AutoUpload(false)
    )
)
```

I need to use a variable from the browser rather than the model for depotID, so I want to do something like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
    .Name("UploadPicker")
    .TemplateId("fileTemplate")
    .Async(a => a
        .Save("UploadDepotLogo", "Depot",new {depotID = $("#DepotID").val() })
        .Remove("Remove", "Upload")
        .AutoUpload(false)
    )
 )
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you can do:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
    .Name("UploadPicker")
    .TemplateId("fileTemplate")
    .Async(a => a
        .Save("UploadDepotLogo", "Depot")
        .Remove("Remove", "Upload")
        .AutoUpload(false)
    )
    .Events(events => events.Upload("onUpload"))
)

<script type="text/javascript">
    function onUpload(e) {
        e.data = { depotID: $("#DepotID").val() };
    }
</script>
```